# How to get the coordinates for a 3D object in python

Tags: python, matplotlib, 3d

I was working on a project that required me to get the 3d points for an object. I already have some basic code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt



fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

x =[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
y =[5,6,2,3,13,4,1,2,4,8]
z =[2,3,3,3,5,7,9,11,9,10]



ax.scatter(x, y, z, c='r', marker='o')

ax.set_xlabel('X Label')
ax.set_ylabel('Y Label')
ax.set_zlabel('Z Label')

plt.show()
```

This basically just plots random points, then opens that with matplotlib. Is there a way to get a file for a 3d image and plot it on something like this (I have no clue how to approach this, would using gcode help)?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you trying to save the plot as a separate file?

Comment: Yes, I do intend to.

Comment: Could you please select the correct answer if you found it suitable.

Answer (score 0):

The following code will save your plot as `.png`

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D



fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

x =[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
y =[5,6,2,3,13,4,1,2,4,8]
z =[2,3,3,3,5,7,9,11,9,10]



ax.scatter(x, y, z, c='r', marker='o')

ax.set_xlabel('X Label')
ax.set_ylabel('Y Label')
ax.set_zlabel('Z Label')

#This saves the picture as a seperate file with the same file path as the .ipynb file
fig.savefig('foo.png', bbox_inches='tight')

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are just looking to download the plot as an image file I would suggest appending the following line of code:

```
fig.savefig('some_name.png', format='png', dpi=100, bbox_inches='tight')
```

If you are looking for an interactive 3D plot, I would suggest you install and use the [plotly](https://plotly.com/) library.

Here is a sample code which outputs a 3D plot similar to the one which you have described above:

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go

x =[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
y =[5,6,2,3,13,4,1,2,4,8]
z =[2,3,3,3,5,7,9,11,9,10]

fig = go.Figure(data=[go.Scatter3d(x=x, y=y, z=z,
                               mode='markers', 
                               marker=dict(size=2))])
fig.show()
fig.write_html("some_plot.html")
```

The plot is saved as an html file which can be viewed and interacted with using a browser.